# Add a string value to all object in json result

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the output of the Jason file:

```
{"children":[{"name":"MyName","value":"MyValue"},{"name":"MyName","value":"MyValue"}]}
```

Now I want it to be like this:
How can I do this using typescript?

```
{"children":[{"data":{"name",:"MyName","value":"MyValue"}},{"data":{"name",:"MyName","value":"MyValue"}}]}
```

This is my code:

```
export class Parent {
  children: Children[];
}

export class Children {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

  GetHtmlFormElements() {
    const children = new Children();
    children.name = 'MyName';
    children.value = 'MyValue';

    const parent = new Parent();
    parent.children = [];
    parent.children.push(children);
    parent.children.push(children);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(parent));
  }
```

Comment: Why do you want it like that? that is not valid JSON

Comment: If you look at your code above, there is no place for data here. can you fix your model first, other wise it's not clear what you want it's structure(Model) to be.

Comment: i use the primeng componetnt .Their structure is as follows

Comment: Can you share the link of library's page

Comment: page related to this model

Comment: link: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/assets/showcase/data/filesystem.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Angular and Primeng,

You can use their own classes for this.

for example,

```
import {TreeNode} from 'primeng/api';

export class dataModel {
    name: string;
    value: string;
}

export interface data {
    data: dataModel;
    children?: TreeNode[];//This should be an array
}
```

here children will be recursive model. you can use it like,

```
data: data;

this.data.children = [
   { data: "//put it here//" },
   { data: "//put it here as well//" }
]
```

of course you can use numerous ways to fill this data object.

> Note: You should definitely use PrimeNg's classes to make your work
>   bit easy.

Answer (score 0):

//can you please try this,

const parent = new Parent();

```
parent.children = [];
let temp_obj = {"data":children};
parent.children.push(temp_obj);
parent.children.push(temp_obj);
```